# Parse csv file to array of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ftp

I just converted some action I did with JS (node) to Python (flask webserver) - connecting to secured FTP service and read and parse a CSV files from there because I know it is faster with Python.
I managed to do almost everything, but I'm having some hard time at parsing the CSV file well.

So this is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import csv
import json
import pysftp
import pandas as pd
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

name = 'username'
password = 'pass'
host = 'hostURL'
path = ""
with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=name, password=password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    for filename in sftp.listdir():
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            file = sftp.open(filename)
            csvFile = file.read()
```

I got to the part where I can see the content of the CSV file but I can't parse well (like I need to it be formatted - array of objects).

I tried to parse it with:

```
with open (csvFile, 'rb') as csv_file:
    print(csv_file)
    cr = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=",") # , is default
    rows = list(cr)
```

and with this:

```
Past=pd.read_csv(csvFile,encoding='cp1252')
print(Past)
```

but I got errors like:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 748: invalid start byte
```

and

```
OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type
```

I'm really kinda stuck right now.
(One more question - not important but just wanted to know if I can retrieve a file from ftp based on the latest date - because sometimes there can be more than 1 file in a repository.)

Comment: You need to isolate the problem better – If you download the CSV file to a local physical file, can you parse the local file with Pandas?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'm so sorry! 
I don't need to download it to a local physical file,
I need to parse it in that scope - because eventually i'm going to send this data to a node server
so i need to read that csv file so i can send that content of the file - or parse the file and transfer it to array of objects - each object will be a row in the CSV file (and the keys are the headers of the file)

Comment: We understand that. But you have to narrow down the problem, if you want our help (and you have to learn how to narrow down the problem anyway, if you are serious in development).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl What do you mean by saying narrow down the problem? I'm at a point where i can access the file - i don't know what to do next.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl if I download the file to a local physical file than i can parse it - but I need to do it without downloading the file.

Comment: So show us a working code, that downloads the file and parses it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl
I really don't understand what you are trying to explain right here.

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't mind using Pandas (and Numpy)**

Pandas' `read_csv` accepts a file path or a file object [(docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). More specifically, it mentions:

> By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as a file handler (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO.

In that sense, using either `filename` or `file` from your example should work.

Given this, if using pandas option, try replacing your code with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='cp1252') # assuming this is the correct encoding
print(df.head()) # optional, prints top 5 entries
```

`df` is now a Pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). To transform a DataFrame into an array of objects, try the `to_numpy` method [(docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```py
arr = df.to_numpy() # returns numpy array from DataFrame
```

Comment: It did not work.
i don't understand how it solves the problem...
How can i implement it in my code?
Eventually i need a variable that contains array of objects (from the CSV file)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl How can i adjust it to my needs?
I just tried to use your code again and it printed the first 5 rows of the CSV - but its still not what i need

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You're right - the docs mention "By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as a file handler (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO." In that sense, I think using both `filename` and `file` from the OP's example should work.

Comment: @NoamAtishkin jut edited the answer to use `to_numpy` to convert to an array. If you need a version without using Pandas, let me know

Comment: @AntónioAlmeida I want to get array of objects evantually.
But if you can help me retrieve the content of the csv file (and i will parse it on my node server) that will be amazing too.
and i would like to know how i can do it without pandas.

Comment: @NoamAtishkin you mentioned on a comment above that you successfully printed the top 5 elements using my example code. That means you "retrieved the content of the csv file" succesfully - that print was just to confirm it. Can you confirm that if you use `read_csv` and then `to_numpy` (as per my answer), you get your array? If so, I'll then help you with a non-pandas version